# How to set different colors on label text in pandas pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I would like to change the label colors for each part of the pie chart in accordance with the color of the section. I find questions doing it with matplotlib (see [Different colors for each label in my pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564641/different-colors-for-each-label-in-my-pie-chart)).
In my case I would like to do it using the creation of the plot with pandas.
Is there a way to create the pie chart with pandas and then access the text of each label to change the color?
Below is an example of my simplified code for which I would like to add a part modifying the colors as it is done in the link above.

```
    index_data = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"]
    data = [10,20,20,40]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=index_data,columns=['col1'])

    color_list = ['#FF7800','#73B22D','#5F5D60','#803C00']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))

    df.plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, y=df.columns[0], legend=False, label='', colors=color_list, autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops={'fontsize': 17})

    # --- I want to change colors here --- #

    plt.show()
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get axis by assigning `df.plot()` to `ax` and then get `texts` attribute from `ax` as below:

```py
index_data = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"]
data = [10,20,20,40]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=index_data,columns=['col1'])

color_list = ['#FF7800','#73B22D','#5F5D60','#803C00']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))

ax = df.plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, y=df.columns[0], legend=False, label='', colors=color_list, autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops={'fontsize': 17})

for text, color in zip(ax.texts, color_list):
    text.set_color(color)

plt.show()
```